# Vue and Javascript API/Object/Array manipulation for searching values

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, vue.js, javascript-objects

Edit to clarify:I have an object from an API response that I get using the mounted function, data is saved not displayed yet.  I need to be able to filter that data by allowing a user to input text in an input box before showing it on the page, then find where that keyword was used in a specific key value(name).  Then show the results on a page but include other key/value pairs from the api array.  This is what the api response looks like:

```
    class: (...)
facets: (...)
numberFound: (...)
results: Array(202)
[0 … 99]
0:
class: "SearchResult"
contentGuid: "7f19462f-6c25-43a9-bdb5-479f5f42fbde"
dateUpdated: "2018-03-27T16:46:31Z"
description: "Converting a Word Document to Adobe Acrobat PDF   Learning Services  Converting a Word Document to Adobe   Acrobat PDF  Enterprise      Converting a Word Document to Adobe Acrobat PDF / Reference ..."
document: Object
documentGuid: "035f5c69-d406-4c16-86ca-de12773a0963"
documentId: 154424
documentVersionId: 44043
fileId: 74213
format: "PDF"
id: "Document#1#44043"
isFavorite: false
languages: "English"
name: "Converting a Word Document to Adobe Acrobat PDF"
numberOfIndexedCoobs: 0
numberOfSharedLinks: 1
packageType: "PDF"
previewId: 74213
publicLinkTokens: Array(1)
resourceType: "Other"
score: 0.0054571675
snippets: Object
updatedById: 994
updatedByName: "Michael"
versionName: "3"
```

For example if someone enters "Adobe" in the search box, I would need to search for the word "adobe" in the name value for the entire object, and only show the ones that have "abobe" somewhere in the name value.

My thought was to get the document name split it, then do an includes() to check for the search term.  This works but I can't seem to figure out how to get it all to work together and get the results on the screen, plus get additional information, such as document Id from the original results. this is what I have so far:

```
async getResults() {
      return axios
        .get(this.url, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Bravais-prod-us-Context": this.getCookie(),
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          this.search = res.data;
          this.search.results.forEach((doc) => {
            this.results = doc.document.name
              .toLowerCase()
              .split(" ")
              .includes(this.termSearch.toLowerCase());
            console.log(doc.document.name.split(" "));
            console.log(this.results);
          });
        })

        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    },
```

I need to show the original title(some words and acronyms are capitalized) plus the doc id(for url links) and a description, all of this info is in the initial api response.

```
<div v-for="" v-bind:key="">
      {{ ???? }}
    </div>
```

That works in the console but how do I get this back together and on the screen??  Any help is appreciated, not looking for someone else to do my coding, just need some advice.

Comment: I would need more information about how this is supposed to work.  Are all the results displayed on the page and then the user can search through them, or is there an input field that after submission returns only the matching result?

Comment: It would be an input field that takes the input to filter the api and then the results are displayed on the page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Edited my question hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by diving your logic. At the moment you have a single function that makes an api call and then searches through the results. It would be better suited to have the api call in a separate method so that if the user searches multiple times it doesn't call the api each time. We can easily solve this by adding an extra method that checks if the results object is populated and decides which methods to call.

Casting all strings to lowercase is a good idea to normalize the data. There might be other ways but this works for it's intended purpose. However, splitting a string is unecessary as the `includes()` method searches through the whole string. [See the MDN docs for `String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

To search within an array you can use the `filter()` method, which will create a new array with all elements that pass the implemented test. [See the MDN docs for `Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

With this in hand, we can write our logic as:

```js
async handleSearch(searchString) {
  if (!this.results.length) {
    this.getResults()
  }
  this.searchResults(searchString)
},

async getResults() {
  return axios.get(this.url, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Bravais-prod-us-Context": this.getCookie(),
      },
    }).then((res) => {
      this.results = res.data.results
    }).catch((error) => console.error(error));
},
  
searchResults(searchString) {
  this.filteredResults = this.results.filter(item => {
    let name = item.name.toLowerCase();
    let searchTerm = searchString.toLowerCase();
    return this.name.includes(searchTerm)
  })
}
```

Your input field will call the `handleSearch()` method, and then you can write you html as such:

```html
<div v-for="result in filteredResults" :key="result.id">
  <p>Name: {{result.name}}</p>
  <p>Description: {{result.description}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If this solution helped you you can mark it as the accepted answer